# when is the useEffect hook clean up function get called in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to know when is the `useEffect` hook clean up function get called in react, Does it get called on dependency change or it get called when component is unmounted.

For example in my component if i have `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{

  return ()=>{ 
             //clean up function code

             }  //clean up function

},[dependency])
```

will the clean up function get's called on `dependency` change or it will get called when the component gets unmounted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will clean up on both case (unmount and on change of dependency) as you have passed `dependency` :

> **When exactly does React clean up an effect?** **[Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)**
>
> React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we
>   learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This
>   is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before
>   running the effects next time.

Comment: I want to know does component unmount on every time state changes, means does component re-rerender on every state change cause component to unmount and mount again, does component unmount on every render

Comment: no, `unmout` is different thing and `re-render` is diff thing, `umount` triggers when component will be removed, and `re-render` is caused by the changes in `props` and `state`to just update the dom

Comment: @user8989, sorry no idea

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on @Vivek Doshi answer. useEffect is synonym to `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined. The effect is run on first render, all subsequent re-renders (unless conditions provided).

Cleanup is run when component unmounts.

To avoid unexpected bugs, react will clear the effect before running new effect. You can play around and grasp the concept with this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-hook-je4h2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: What do mean that it also run useEffect when component unmount, as far I know on unmount of a component only cleanup function runs.

Comment: I meant to cleanup, I have made changes to the post. Thanks!